# Constrain TypeScript union based on property value

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that defines some types like the following (simplified for demonstration purposes).

```js
type RequestA = { a: string };
type RequestB = { b: string };
type RequestC = { c: string };

export type Properties = Record<string, {
    prop_a: RequestA;
    type: 'prop_a';
} | {
    prop_b: RequestB;
    type: 'prop_b';
} | {
    prop_c: RequestC;
    type: 'prop_c';
}>;
```

I then define a number of helper types using generics that ultimately result in a type equivalent to the following. The key point here is that the value of the `type` property in each union member matches the return type of the `request` function—i.e. `prop_a` corresponds to `RequestA`, `prop_b` to `RequestB`, etc.

```js
type Definition = {
    name: string;
    type: 'prop_a';
    request: () => RequestA;
} | {
    name: string;
    type: 'prop_b';
    request: () => RequestB;
} | {
    name: string;
    type: 'prop_c';
    request: () => RequestC;
};
```

My goal is to then construct a `Properties` object based on an array of `Definition` objects.

```js
const properties: Properties = {};

const definitions: Definition[] = [
    {
        name: 'A Prop',
        type: 'prop_a',
        request: () => ({ a: 'A value' }),
    },
    {
        name: 'B Prop',
        type: 'prop_b',
        request: () => ({ b: 'B value' }),
    },
    {
        name: 'C Prop',
        type: 'prop_c',
        request: () => ({ c: 'C value' }),
    },
];

for (const definition of definitions) {
    const { name, type, request } = definition;
    const value = request()

    const property = {
        type,
        [type]: value,
    };

    properties[name] = property;
}
```

However, the final line (`properties[name] = property`) raises the following error.

```
Type '{ [x: string]: RequestA | RequestB | RequestC | "prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"; type: "prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"; }' is not assignable to type '{ prop_a: RequestA; type: "prop_a"; } | { prop_b: RequestB; type: "prop_b"; } | { prop_c: RequestC; type: "prop_c"; }'.
  Property 'prop_c' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: RequestA | RequestB | RequestC | "prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"; type: "prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"; }' but required in type '{ prop_c: RequestC; type: "prop_c"; }'.
```

Is there a way to constrain the types so TypeScript knows that the `type` and `request` properties of a `definition` are related to each other?

[Code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYBBKBeKBvKAhgFxRoBOAlgHYDmUAvgNwCwAUKJLAsmgELZ4oAIxLlqdJmw7Q4SVMADCA-AGNRwSrQYtWbCAA8wAezLAo0qAAUyRyKYqoBcFSYAmAHjG0ANHjZQAqDAbMAB9Yi45NHQdQPNwCBIAcmDbcKSdeigAHz9WONSwkUieYF5YwOlkwtChDLYs3Nx-QJq1EvkFCoCqqBSQ0JV61noAPh02NgB6Gdm5+YXFpeWV1dXJ3XYEqAARCAAzagpgCiMqZRaAqgIAW0TSDXFu+MhqgYJhuLJueRIACgAlNhRh1opkcnk4tc7upNDRnr1+mk6s9vlFgP8gVgQbJSuUGhDmvlAtD7l54ZcXvckWEhqifmhMcDQYpMhNNmtOVzuTzFhs2C4qGggiEIPZUCRrLYxSdHDhcJJNoLha4DkcTmcUCQ9ocqMdTlQANoAXQEhspRLiUNu1MwUrASW8lLiiJqHydxKtUDRpSZ2Kgf3wESSmAAbgQADbIJIMAEeuL0eOBS1eqCk5L8e2O52VBJvZHZz1Wn2-ANYkGB4QZqDhqMQGP0OOUxMWnNXG3JJRZpNe10DIY94sMjFl5mV9pJJS16Oxwct1jG9n7EwB5VmVW6-VnKBGfZQDfqg0oIEpgJrwSk3zSXwl4VZHAHvUaqjPc-T6A4W-AQEbOLnwoyiAFxFi6CSDnEhrSMaJDvnO7IFKK4ooIapKmjgAGmCAmRsEAA)

Comment: This looks like an instance of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) which might not be easily solvable with [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  I haven't been able to do it without type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvYJBm), which means we might as well just assert without the "distributive object" refactoring, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyOGJN).  I will look again when I get a chance but I'm not seeing anything type safe without redundancy.

Comment: Let the compiler figure out the types